# Nodejs - mongodb cannot get sparse index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, node-mongodb-native

I am using `node-mongodb-native` as the MongoDb driver for my Node.js application. Here is my insertion function:

```
async create(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const datetime = Date.parse(new Date());
            data._id = new ObjectID().toString();
            data.createdAt = datetime;
            data.updatedAt = datetime;
            data.deleted = false;
            this._db.collection(this._table).ensureIndex({ 'body.flowid': 1 },
                { unique: true, dropDups: true, sparse: true },
                async (err) => {
                    if (err) { return reject('Duplicate phone number'); }
                    try {
                        await this._db.collection(this._table).insertOne(data);
                        return resolve(data);
                    } catch (error) {
                        return reject(error.message);
                    }
                });
        });
    }
```

With sparse index on `'body.flowid` field, I am supposed to only index that field when it exists in document. Then I tried to insert two documents with the same `body.flowid` into the collection. None of two insertions succeeded. It threw error like this:

[image: Here it threw the error of duplicate index value]

But after that, when I tried to get the indexes of this collection. I could not find it!

[image: Here we see only the primary <code>_id</code> index exists]

I don't get what happened here. How to fix this?

Comment: `ensureIndex` is deprecated, please use `createIndex`. `dropDups` was deprecated many years ago and has actually been removed. `body.flowId` sounds suspiciously like it *might* be a field within an array, in which case `unique` indexes should not be created on arrays. At any rate, any kind of data at all on that path will negate the `sparse`. Show some sample documents that this would apply to if you are still unsure.